# How to apply multiple conditions from one cell for SUMIF | GoogleSheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, sumifs, multiple-conditions

Do you have an idea for a function that would sum **the amounts** from **table 2** based on `Unique_nr` from Table 1?

I tried to do it this way:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(E3:E9,{SPLIT(A3,",")},F3:F9))) <---doesn't work

=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(E3:E9,{"8-1","9-1"},F3:F9))) <----It works
```

Theoretically the **SPLIT()** function gives the same result as I type manually, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

I would like to do this with one function for the entire range of data

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JGvFIZIE6c_D0A2Z4xCWf7pxqVft4Zsb6S-45_d9LY4/edit?usp=sharing
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You were almost in the correct way

First of all, remove the double quotes from the cells.

By default SPLIT will `Divide text around a specified character or string` and it means there will be an extra step in order to use this output to another function, it's possible that your cell had an extra character and the [TRIM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140) function will solve it.

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(E3:E9,{trim(SPLIT(A3,","))},F3:F9)))
```

### You can use VLOOKUP and SUM as a different approach

As you mentioned [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) is a good approach to treat comma-separated cells. In order to avoid unexpected spaces [TRIM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140) is a good option (it's optional) as well as [IFNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944) in order to fill that cell in case there's not a match.

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IFNA(vlookup(trim(split(A3,",")),E3:F9,2,0))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find a better option, you can use a dragable formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM($F$3:F*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$3:E,A3)))))
```

[image]